# How to delete in mysql version 5.7

Tags: mysql

how to delete duplicate rows in mysql version 5.7?

here's my code and im getting error

> Error Code: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

How to fix please?

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE code AND cl_date IN (
SELECT code, cl_date FROM( SELECT 
    code, cl_date, 
    COUNT(cl_date)
FROM
    table1) AS a
    WHERE code = "code1" AND cl_date BETWEEN '2021-03-21' AND '2021-04-1'
GROUP BY cl_date
HAVING COUNT(cl_date) > 1) 
ORDER BY cl_date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `.. WHERE (code, cl_date) IN ( ..`. But this is not the only problem. Subquery `a` have no GROUP BY clause...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that works for me.

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT MAX(id) AS lastId, cl_date
   FROM table1
   WHERE code = "code1" AND closed BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-04-30'
  GROUP BY cl_date
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dup ON dup.cl_date = table1.cl_date
WHERE table1.id < dup.lastId
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, it is not possible to have two columns with the "IN" operator. You can use the following command if you want to delete duplicate rows based on "code" and "cl_date" columns:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id Not IN (
    SELECT 
        MIN(id)
    FROM
        table1
        WHERE code = "code1" AND cl_date BETWEEN '2021-03-21' AND '2021-04-1'
    GROUP BY cl_date
    ) and code = "code1"
```

This query keeps the first occurance of duplicate rows in the table by using "MIN(id)" and discards the others. The last row can be kept by using "MAX(id)" instead.

Comment: Error Code: 1093
You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I have tried the same code in MariaDB. what is your mysql version? you can also try this code : DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id Not IN (  select id from (
SELECT 
    MIN(id) as id
FROM
    table1
    WHERE code = "code1" AND cl_date BETWEEN '2021-03-21' AND '2021-04-1'
GROUP BY cl_date ) TBL
) and code = "code1"

Comment: im using 5.7 version

Comment: Did you try new sql in the comment?. It should solve your problem.